# g++ - not reflecting changes made in source file

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I'm building a project with a structure like this:

```
- Makefile
- main.cpp
- util.h
- subsrc/
  - one.cpp
  - two.cpp
```

And I have my Makefile set up to output to a build directory:

```
all: $(BIN_FILE)

$(BIN_FILE): $(OBJ_FILES)
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
    g++ $^ -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    g++ -c $^ -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/subsrc/%.o: subsrc/%.cpp
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)/subsrc
    g++ -c $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*
```

However, I'm seeing this issue when I run g++ manually as well, so I don't think it's related to the Makefile.

I can build from clean and everything works fine. The issue is when I change one of the subsrc files and try to recompile, via `make` or by running these commands myself:

```
g++ -c subsrc/one.cpp -o build/obj/subsrc/one.o
g++ build/obj/main.o build/obj/subsrc/one.o build/obj/subsrc/two.o -o build/bin/prog
```

If I do this, changes made in `one.cpp` are **not reflected** in the binary output. If I recompile `main.cpp` (or, of course, the entire project), it works fine. This is not an issue of g++ not properly overwriting files, since even if I `rm build/obj/subsrc/one.o` and/or `rm build/bin/prog` before running the above commands, I still don't see the changes. That makes no sense to me and I have no idea what's happening.

EDIT: I have uploaded a minimum reproducible example here. https://github.com/scatter-dev/so_70242118_min_repro

Reproduction instructions:

1. Build using `make` or by running the g++ commands above.
2. Run the program to ensure it has built correctly.
3. Change the output of the `doWork` function in `one.cpp`. Save to disk.
4. Rerun `make` and note that the `one.o` file is recompiled and `prog` is recreated with the linker.
5. Run the program again and see that the output has not changed.

At the suggestion of a commenter, I checked the md5sum of `one.o` and `prog` between steps 1 and 4 and they are indeed both the same. This remains the case **even if I delete `one.o` before recompiling**. Yes, I am sure that `one.cpp` is being saved to disk (its md5sum does change, along with the fact that `make clean && make` will compile using the new changes).

Comment: How do you know that the changes are not reflected in the binary?

Comment: please show a [mre]. are the changes perhaps in a header file?

Comment: A common reason is that the changes are only in the editor, and not saved to disk.

Comment: You can check the md5sum of build/bin/prog before and after your change, to see if it's being updated.   Do the same to one.o and one.cpp.   That might narrow your search as to where your problem is occurring (note: assuming no `__DATE__` strings in one.cpp...)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've added a minimal reproducible example. The changes are not in a header file.

Comment: @j6t I'm changing (or adding or removing) strings that are printed to stdout. Running the binary does not print the new output unless I fully rebuild including main.

Comment: @BoP This is not the case, and I'm quite sure because `make clean && make` works as expected.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry I've done so and both one.o and prog have the same md5sum as before. one.cpp does not.

Comment: There is something weird because your makefile contains `mkdir` commands, but the output you show doesn't have any `mkdir` commands in them.

Comment: @MadScientist When I run make, it does show the mkdir commands. That wasn't meant to be make output, just the commands I was running (since the issue does occur whether or not it's compiled through make). Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: a [mre] should be contained within the question itself without relying on external links

Comment: `#include "one.cpp"`, don't do that, your code is in the header file, just because its named `.cpp` doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your code is weirdly written and as a result, your makefile is incomplete.

In your main.cpp you have:

```
#include "subsrc/derived.h"
```

which is fine but in that header you have:

```
#include "one.cpp"
#include "two.cpp"
```

which is extremely bizarre.  You pretty much never want to include `.cpp` files in other source files (or in header files).  It's just a bad idea.

In this situation, ALL the content of your program is included into `main.cpp` and thus appears in your `main.o` file.  Linking in the other objects (`one.o` and `two.o`) is useless and unnecessary: they are ignored.

In your makefile, however, you don't list `one.cpp` or `two.cpp` as prerequisites of `main.o`, which means that when you modify these source files `main.o` is not updated, and so nothing changes.  If you remove `main.o`, then it is recompiled and you get the new behavior.

**ETA**

You have two options:

You can either put the declaration of the classes into `derived.h` and put the definition of the **doWork()** method into the `.cpp` files.  That would look like this:

```
$ cat main.cpp
#include "subsrc/derived.h"
...

$ cat subsrc/derived.h
#include "../base.h"
class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    void doWork();
};
class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    void doWork();
};

$ cat subsrc/one.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "derived.h"
void Derived1::doWork() {
    std::cout << "I'm Derived1" << std::endl;
}

$ cat subsrc/two.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "derived.h"
void Derived2::doWork()
{
    std::cout << "I'm Derived2" << std::endl;
}

$ cat Makefile
...
$(OBJ_DIR)/main.o : base.h subsrc/derived.h
$(OBJ_DIR)/subsrc/one.o: base.h subsrc/derived.h
$(OBJ_DIR)/subsrc/two.o: base.h subsrc/derived.h
```

Or you can inline everything in a header file the way you're doing (but you really don't want to name these files with `.cpp` extensions, if they contain class declarations).  Or you can just have one `derived.h` and throw away `one.cpp` and `two.cpp` altogether.

But you need to add the prerequisites in the makefile: if you keep multiple headers then `main.o` must depend on them.

Comment: This makes sense, but what's the proper way to write this? If I change derived.h to declare the classes rather than include them, I get incomplete type errors, which sort of makes sense, but I only want to use functions that are defined in the base class, so I shouldn't have to define the full type. Plus, wouldn't the same problem arise then if I make changes to derived.h?

Comment: Yes, you have to list the prerequisites if you want the makefile to work.  There are ways to have make automatically generate these dependencies if you want.

Comment: Regarding the content of derived.h, I think what you want is for `main.cpp` to include `base.h`, and then `one.cpp` and `two.cpp` also to include `base.h`, and that's it.  You don't need `derived.h` at all.

Comment: Well it's back to the whole reason I made `derived.h` in the first place - I don't see how I can create an instance of the derived classes in `main.cpp` unless I include the entire class somehow. Even if I declare them as derived from `Base`, it still complains about incomplete type, even though there's no explicitly defined constructor anyway and I'm only using functions that are defined in `Base`.

Comment: I appreciate the edit! Having to declare doWork() in each of the derived classes seems pretty cumbersome, but I see that it will work. I think I'll open another question about this since my initial question has been answered now. But I plan to have several of these derived classes and I'd like to keep the code as DRY as possible, so I'd love to have some more in-depth discussion about it.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it, it all depends on what works best in your specific situation.